# Symbol's function definition is void: elpy-enable

Tags: emacs

I'm using Emacs 24 and trying to use the `elpy` package, and getting the error:

"Symbol's function definition is void: elpy-enable"

```
(package-initialize)
(elpy-enable)
(elpy-use-ipython)
```

The mode I'm using (elpy) just said to add those lines to my .emacs file and it would all be fine (I've installed this mode on the python side).

Loading emacs with `--debug-init` provides the following

```
  (elpy-enable)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/tk12098/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 354
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/tk12098/.emacs" "/home/tk12098/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" t t)
  #[0 "\205\262
```

The line starting `#[0 "....` seems to go on for a while.

How should I go about solving this?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Can't remember what I did, but here's my init.el https://github.com/TomKealy/emacs/blob/master/init.el

Comment: I also switched to spacemacs at the start of the year, and that has a great python mode.

Comment: Thanks, I will give a look on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding this to my `~/.emacs.d/init.el`:

```
(require 'elpy)
(elpy-enable)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the `elpy` package before you can enable it.

Depending on how you installed it, you can do `(require 'elpy)` or something like it.

E.g.,

```
(when (load "full/path/to/elpy" t)
  (elpy-enable)
  (elpy-use-ipython))
```

PS. Did you actually do what is described in the [official docs](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy)? (Specifically, `package-install`)

Comment: I don't think that this is the real issue.  `elpy-enable` is autoloaded:  Calling it would automatically load Elpy anyway.